# UIWebView injection hide navbar in webViewDidStartLoad

Tags: ios, cocoa, uiwebview

I am developing an app where i use an UIWebView that loads an url. I would like to hide the navigation bar (which is the first div) so i implemented the following that works fine :

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
// finished loading, hide the activity indicator in the status bar
[self activityIndicatorAnimate:NO];
[self.browser stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var script = document.createElement('script');"  
 "script.type = 'text/javascript';"  
 "script.text = \"function myFunction() { "
 "var b=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];b.style.visibility='hidden';"
 "}\";"  
 "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"];  
[self.browser stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunction();"];

NSLog(@"%@", [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.all[0].innerHTML"]);

}
```

The fact is that this gets executed when the document has been loaded and because it takes time for the url to download, the navbar remains visible while loading. Is there anyway i can make it to hide the navbar from the beginning ?

**Note**: If i add this code in webViewDidStartLoad it does not execute because the elements are not yet loaded.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to hide it before the content loading over, but I am thinking an alternative one - you can just load an local html to the webview and then by using ajax to load the page, in the response of ajax, do something with html, and then display it in your webview. To load a local file to your webview, check these codes -

```
NSString *html = [NSString alloc];

html = @"index.htm";
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle]; 
NSString *path = [bundle bundlePath];

NSString *fullPath = [NSBundle pathForResource:html ofType:nil inDirectory:path];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath];
url = [url URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];

url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"index.htm?page=1" relativeToURL:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


[self.mHtmlViewer loadRequest:request];
```

Remember to add your html to your project by drag them into the project.